# Adjusting jQuery script to add height to parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Soh Tanaka's script to toggle open and closed div content in the accordion style.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                //Hide (Collapse) the toggle containers on load
                $(".toggle_container").hide(); 

                //Switch the "Open" and "Close" state per click then slide up/down (depending on open/close state)
                $("h3.trigger").click(function(){
                    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");

                    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
                });

            });
</script>
```

I'm trying to adapt this script so that the toggle also adds an increase of 50px to the height of a container div with the id of #join_find_talk. Help, please...

You can see it in action here: http://www.snakeandherring.com.au/join/

Comment: It would be nice if you could include some HTML and further describe what you mean with "toggles an increase of 50px".

Comment: Im using the script to toggle content, you can see it in action here: snakeandherring.com.au/dev/#join_find_talk. If you click on the Find link you can see an accordion menu listing locations. I'm trying to create a solution where the background also expands when several locations are opened.... Hope thats clear?

Comment: I think I might starting to understand what you´re trying to do. The content area (#find_content) gets larger than the background image but you want the background to grow with it, don´t you?

Comment: @Stefan, yes you have it. That is exactly what the problem is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use Javascript to increase the height of an element by a defined amount. This is what CSS is for.

What Javascript can help you do, however, is do the dynamic part. So, instead of changing the height of an element, add a class to it. This will let you change your sizing later without ever having to edit the Javascript.

An example:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #join_find_talk { height: 100px; }
  #join_find_talk.expanded { height: 150px; }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("h3.trigger").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Use this, not return false;
    $("#join_find_talk").toggleClass("expanded");
  });
</script>
```

Notice that no height/width info appears in the Javascript. This is separation of style from logic. It's a good thing :)

Comment: there is more than one .trigger on the page, if I use toggle class then the second .trigger removes the "expanded" class. While an elegant solution is not one I can implement on this page.

Comment: In that case, your question is unclear. You state "I'm trying to adapt this script so that the toggle also adds an increase of 50px to the height of a container". What are you actually wanting to do?

Comment: Im using the script to toggle content, you can see it in action here: http://www.snakeandherring.com.au/dev/#join_find_talk. If you click on the Find link you can see an accordion menu listing locations. I'm trying to create a solution where the background also expands when several locations are opened.... Hope thats clear?